# discord.js Variable Counting

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a little problem with variables in discord.js

This code:

```
testvariable = testvariable + 1;
```

supposes to add 1 number to itself, but it doesn't. Can anybody help?

Comment: It does. The problem should be where you use the variable. Try to provide more code and errors if there are any.

Comment: Show your code that needs the variable ! 
```testvariable = testvariable + 1;``` should work just fine.
You could also do this : testvariable++; to also increment the variable by 1

Comment: well, thats it. I am trying to add a command that adds 1 number to itself. And then a command that displays what number that variable holds. The code of the command is `return message.channel.send("Variable holds number " + testvariable);

Comment: Do provide a longer snippet of code. It may be an issue with scopes or when your adding  statement gets run.

Answer (score 0):

To add one to a variable you can use the following operations
`test_int++`
`test_int += 1`
`test_int -=- 1`
`test_int = (test_int + 1)`

from what you said you want to have a command that adds to a variable. You can do something along the lines of

```js
function command_increase(test_int, message) 
{
  if(!test_int || !message) return; // returns void if missing a parameter

  test_int++ // add one to the test_int variable

  message.channel.send(`Variable holds number: ${test_int}`) // send message
  return; // return void;
}

// on bot start (outside of the actual command to prevent the variable from being set to 0)
var test_int = 0;


// command handler;
if (command == "!increase")
    command_increase(test_int, message)
```

if you would like your variable to keep its value after restarting, I would recommend using a database or writing to a json file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally know what's going on. Well the bot sent a message before adding the number to the variable, so it didn't do anything.